# Why doesn't chrome load videos immersive

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, chrome-for-android, immersive-mode

Here's what a video frame looks like on CM browser: [image: Fits Full Screen]
Here's what a video frame  looks like on Chrome:

[image: Doesn't fit Screen]
That upper black border is for the status bar(the status bar is not there, but that's its place). The borders on the sides are for nothing... probably the video is fitted with respect to height.

This doesn't happen with YouTube videos on Chrome, But that's the only site where Chrome works fine.
How can I fix this please.